# QGIS-Pycharm-QT Reference not found

Tags: pycharm, qgis, python-3.9, pyqgis

I know it is a never ending story and there a lot of articles around and I tried a lot of the tips without no success.
Maybe I should also mention, that I had a lot of different versions of QGIS installed.
The last one which was functioning in Pycharm was QGIS 3.16.

My System:
Windows 10
QGIS 3.22.14
Pycharm 2022.3.1 CE

My batch file:

```
SET QGISNAME=qgis-ltr
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%

CALL %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat

SET PATH=%PATH%;%QGIS%\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts

SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%QGIS%\python
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39

rem SET QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

SET PYCHARM="c:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\bin\pycharm64.exe"

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS" /B %PYCHARM% %*
```

My Problem:

[image]

I tried also "repair IDE" in Pycharm.
The last litte success was setting the interpreter to python-qgis-ltr.bat
so I got the reference to qgis itself.

Can anyone help me please?